# R : Add dynamic column name to row in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Sample Data :

```
df <- data.frame(ProdCode = c("C1","C2"), ProdName = c("Product 1", "Product 2"), Category = c("Categ 1", "Categ 2"), "Jan-16" = c(3,2), "Apr-16" = c(3,""), "Jul-16" = c(5,2), "Oct-16" = c(5,2))
```

The value corresponding each month and product cell is rating for that product. That need to be in Rating column in output dataframe:

```
> df
  ProdCode  ProdName Category Jan.16 Apr.16 Jul.16 Oct.16
1       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      3      3      5      5
2       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      2             2      2
```

I've above data which is required in below format:

```
ProdCode  Product.Name  Category    Rating.Date   Rating
C1          Product 1   Categ 1     Jan-16         3
C1          Product 1   Categ 1     Apr-16         3
C1          Product 1   Categ 1     Jul-16         5
C1          Product 1   Categ 1     Oct-16         5
C2          Product 2   Categ 2     Jan-16         2
C2          Product 2   Categ 2     Jul-16         2
C2          Product 2   Categ 2     Oct-16         2
```

The month column are dynamic and it will increase such as in future as per product it will come as Jan-2017 etc. I could do it by using for loop but that won't worth of using R.

Comment: Have look at the `reshape2` package, and specifically the `melt()` function

Comment: check tidyr::gather

Comment: @mpjdem, yeah melt() can work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the different other options we have :

Note : you have the liberty to name the last 2 columns, I kept it to the default(variable and value)

using `melt() from data.frame`

```
library(reshape2)
df1 = melt(df, id.vars = c("ProdCode" , "ProdName" ,"Category"), measure.vars = 4:7)
df1 = df1[df1$value != "",]
```

using `melt from data.table)`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) 
melt.data.table(df, 1:3,4:7)[value!=""]  # '1:3, 4:7' are the column indexes. read more from ?melt

#  ProdCode  ProdName Category variable value
#1       C1 Product 1  Categ 1   Jan.16     3
#2       C2 Product 2  Categ 2   Jan.16     2
#3       C1 Product 1  Categ 1   Apr.16     3
#5       C1 Product 1  Categ 1   Jul.16     5
#6       C2 Product 2  Categ 2   Jul.16     2
#7       C1 Product 1  Categ 1   Oct.16     5
#8       C2 Product 2  Categ 2   Oct.16     2

# if you want your specific column names :

melt.data.table(df, 1:3,4:7, variable.name = "Rating.Date", value.name = "Rating")[Rating!=""]
#   ProdCode  ProdName Category Rating.Date Rating
#1:       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Jan.16      3
#2:       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Jan.16      2
#3:       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Apr.16      3
#4:       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Jul.16      5
#5:       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Jul.16      2
#6:       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Oct.16      5
#7:       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Oct.16      2
```

Comment: Just use `melt()` - if you give it a `data.table`, it will call `melt.data.table` under the hood

Comment: @DavidArenburg more clean code, and faster in my observation

Comment: thanks for the comment. @DavidArenburg i need to get the facts correct..

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gather` to reshape it to 'long', `filter` out the blanks in 'Rating' and `arrange` by 'ProdCode'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df, Rating.Date, Rating, Jan.16:Oct.16) %>%
            filter(Rating !="") %>%
            arrange(ProdCode) 
#  ProdCode  ProdName Category Rating.Date Rating
#1       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Jan.16      3
#2       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Apr.16      3
#3       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Jul.16      5
#4       C1 Product 1  Categ 1      Oct.16      5
#5       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Jan.16      2
#6       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Jul.16      2
#7       C2 Product 2  Categ 2      Oct.16      2
```

Comment: There is no rating and rating.date in df @akrun

Comment: @user_az That are the key and value name we provide to be created in the output